# Dilation with Trackbar Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on image proccessing and I trouble in dilation of image with trackbar. I can see trackbar in window but the problem is that it doesn't work on image. I mean while I am changing dilation value in trackbar, there is not changing in image. İt is working for thresh value ı dont have problem with that.

```
def trackChaned(x):
  pass

cv2.namedWindow('Thresh')

cv2.createTrackbar("Thresh Value", "Thresh",0,255,trackChaned)
cv2.createTrackbar("Dilation Value", "Thresh", 0,50,trackChaned)
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.3, fy=0.3)

while(True):
   threshValue = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Thresh Value", "Thresh")
   dilationValue = cv2.getTrackbarPos("dilation Value", "Thresh")

   ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,threshValue,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(thresh1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

   kernal = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
   dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, kernal, iterations= dilationValue)
   cv2.imshow("threshValue",thresh1)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
       break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imshow('Test', thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(thresh1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow('Test', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine. But two typos caused your problem.

Firstly, always check the name you registered.
In your while loop, you're getting information from `dilation Value`, while you set the trackbar name as `Dilation Value`. So you'll need to fix that.

```
cv2.createTrackbar("Dilation Value", "Thresh", 0,50,trackChaned)
dilationValue = cv2.getTrackbarPos("dilation Value", "Thresh")
```

Secondly, your showing `thresh1` image instead of `dilation`. So you won't visually find any changes whatsoever. Change that to `dilation` and you're good to go.

```
(in while loop)
cv2.imshow("threshValue",thresh1)
```

When you do dilations, I would suggest you add a third trackbar to find the most suitable `kernel size` as well.